# Convert HTML Table to div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to convert this table layout to its CSS equivalent using divs.

```
<table class="ourwork-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0476-01-responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Style for the table:

```
    .ourwork-table {
        width:100%;
    }

    .ourwork-table img {
          width: 100%;
          display:block;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: And what's the question you forgot to ask?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.row{
 width: 100%
}
.item{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: It works, however, it doesnt stay contained in the wrapper it is in. How would I force that "row width:100%" to be contained in a parent div?

Comment: Well I don't know the layout of the parent div so I wouldn't know. Post the code and I'll check it out